# How to compare Random Forest and Gaussian Process models on a regression problem?

Tags: random-forest, gaussian-process, fitting, model-comparison

I want to compare the model fitting properties of a Random Forest (RF) and a Gaussian Process (GP) on a regression problem. One way I thought of is by using mean-squared error values on a hold-out dataset. **What are other ways of comparing the two models?**

Since GPs are probabilistic models, we can also visualize the model posterior over the test dataset (for low input dimensions) but I am not sure whether we can do the same thing for RF models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea about using a hold-out set for comparing the RMSE is fine. I would note though that if we do not have rather a large hold-out sample, using a repeated cross-validation approach instead of a fixed hold-out set will mitigate finite-sample variance  issues; repeated CV is preferable because it allows to also estimate the variability of our test statistics. Other test statistics like the mean absolute error ([MAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_error)) or the mean absolute percentage error ([MAPE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_percentage_error) - for positive only data) might also be relevant depending on the application.

Regarding visualising the posterior: We can obtain an empirical distribution for each fit through a [quantile random forest](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume7/meinshausen06a/meinshausen06a.pdf) (see Fig. 3 & 4 from the linked paper). Implementations in [R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quantregForest/index.html) and [Python](https://scikit-garden.github.io/examples/QuantileRegressionForests/) are already available.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Do you also know if there are any likelihood based approaches for Random forests as well?

Comment: Not really I am afraid. I have some work like the one on: [A Very Simple Safe-Bayesian Random Forest](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/30612011.pdf) but I haven't seen it catching up a lot. In general, [BART](https://arxiv.org/abs/0806.3286)s (Bayesian additive regression trees) sit squarely on the notion that we use a likelihood (and a prior) to grow an ensemble of trees. They are much more closely related to boosting than simple bagging like RFs are but the principles are very similar.

Comment: These are the good references. Thank you.